# how to give width of ListBox in HTML5

Tags: html, listbox

I want to give ListBox width in HTML5.
Please give me some idea.

Comment: What's a listbox? After a quick Google, I came across this: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm#demos/jqxlistbox/rendering.htm Apparently there's a width setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can style it as a regular input - all CSS properties applicable to it

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxRWu/)

---

***CSS***

```
input[list] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<input type="text" list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">    
    <option> Chrome </option>   
    <option> Firefox </option>
    <option> IE9 </option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
style="width:150px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#example {
    width: 300px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select size="4" id="example" name="example">
<option selected>Fries</option>
<option>Drink</option>
<option>Pie</option>
<option>Salad</option>
<option>Shake</option>
</select>
```

For completeness and to show an actual HTML5 Listbox (no JS needed).